# fadeOut a (flash)video within a modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, html5-video

I have a modal dialog showing a video and a photogallery, each in a div with some additional content. The video-div is supposed to fade out on click, which works like a charm in safari and FF (html5 video) but in ie7 and 8 using flowplayer the video doesn't fade but suddenly disappears after all other elements in the div have faded out.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Lutz

Comment: What wmode are you using?  Try a different one?

Answer (score 0):

Flash is a separate browser plug-in unlike the HTML5 that is built into the browsers. I doubt that any browser plugins in any browser supports opacity, which would be required to fade out.